# Golang http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls

Tags: go, websocket

These days I was working on send message via websoket,using Beego framework.
but meet the wrong message http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
Where is the problem?
Any tips would be great!

```
func (this *WsController) Get() {
    fmt.Println("connected")
    handler(this.Ctx.ResponseWriter, this.Ctx.Request, this);
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(this.Ctx.ResponseWriter, this.Ctx.Request, nil)
    if _, ok := err.(websocket.HandshakeError); ok {
        http.Error(this.Ctx.ResponseWriter, "Not a websocket handshake", 400)
        return
    } else if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("connected")
    connection := consumer.New(beego.AppConfig.String("LoggregatorAddress"), &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}, nil)

    fmt.Println("===== Tailing messages")
    msgChan, err := connection.Tail(this.Ctx.Input.Param(":appGuid"), this.Ctx.Input.Param(":token"))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("===== Error tailing: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        for msg := range msgChan {
            // if  closeRealTimeLogFlag{
            //  consumer.Close()
            //  break
            // }
            if err = conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, msg.Message); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("%v \n", msg)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what does the `handler` function do?

Comment: http.Error() calls WriteHeader. So either your handler already called WriteHeader, or upgrader.Upgrade calls Writeheader on the ResponseWriter.

Comment: The upgrader calls http.Error by default. Unless you set a do nothing error function in the upgrader, you should not call http.Error in the application code.

Comment: Thanks for all of you, It is very helpful. The problem has been solved.

Comment: @EthianWu Could you please answer your own question, and approve it...

Answer (score -4):

because you write more than statusCode